# Java Keystore.aliases() - different implementations between IBM and Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, keystore

I have a certificate that was issued by my (private) CA. When I'm loading it to the Java KeyStore and call the `aliases()` function, I get different results between Oracle JVM (on Windows) and IBM JVM (on linux).

On Oracle, I get only one alias - my certificate's CN - "my_cert",
and on IBM I get two aliases - "my_cert" and "my_ca".

I use the KeyStore for loading the CA certificate  out of my certificate.
On Oracle, I can do it without knowing the certificate's CN - just call 
to `aliases()`, which returns only one alias, get its chain, and from its chain get the higest certificate  - the CA certificate . (My code is below).
On IBM, I can't do it, since I have two aliases and I have to distinguish between them first.

Long story short, I have three questions:

1. Can I load a password protected file without using the KeyStore?
2. Are the different `aliases()` results related to the host platforms (Windows/Linux)?
3. Can I use the Java IBM KeyStore for extracting my CA certificate without knowing my certificate alias?

My code:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");

ks.load(new FileInputStream(ICA_CERT_PATH), pass.toCharArray());

String alias = ks.aliases().nextElement();

Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);

 /* Takes the highest certificate from chain - the root CA */
icaCert =  (X509Certificate) chain[chain.length - 1];
```

Comment: Is this the same physical KeyStore being accessed by two JDKs? Or two different keystores? It seems to be the latter, built by two different commands.

Comment: It is the same p12 file.